# 'Is believed to' usage

Tags: phrase-usage, infinitives, singular-vs-plural, participles, reported-speech

I was studying a book '*Grammar In Use*'. 
But there is a sentence I don't understand.

'A number of paintings is believed to have been destroyed'

Why 'to' has to be used in this sentence? 
Also, are these wrong sentences if I say,

1. A number of paintings have been believed being destroyed.
2. A number of paintings is believed destroyed.

Comment: related: [“is said to” causes ambiguity](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13421/is-said-to-causes-ambiguity)

Comment: Many **people** believe that _(it's common belief)_ **somebody/something** _(we don't know who/what or it's not important)_ destroyed the painting. See [passive perfect infinitives](http://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-infinitive)

Answer (score 1):

Consider "is believed to" as a modifying clause.

> A number of paintings <del>is believed to</del> have been destroyed.
>   A number of paintings have been destroyed.

The destruction has actually happened.

> A number of paintings *is believed to* have been destroyed.

Here it is second-hand information which may or may not be true.
I don't think you need to rewrite any further.

Comment: correct, but it should be "are believed to". "a number of paintings" conjugates as plural http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/numbers/the-number-vs-a-number/